# How close am I to getting another gold badge?

Tags: support

I'm not exactly over the moon about the way SE has implemented their decision to grant me the power to [unilaterally close questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4807/have-i-just-been-granted-superpowers) - but if history has taught me anything, it's that you can't fight City Hall (or indeed [TPTB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_powers_that_be_%28phrase%29) in general, and specifically those at SE).

It's important to note that this new ability only applies to *duplicate* closevotes, and even then only if I have a [gold badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers?tab=badges) for at least one the tags on the question.

Since I see [little chance they'll reconsider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231625/153229), and actually provide a *reminder* when my closevote is "supercharged", I suddenly find I need to pay more attention to my badge status. Currently my only relevant gold badge is for [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/130/single-word-requests?userid=2637).  But I've got a dozen silver badges for other categories - and so far as I know, any of those could become gold badges at any time.

I know that *Gold = Earned at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers*, and *Silver = Earned at least 400 total score for at least 80 answers*. What I *don't* know is how close I am to gaining more "question category" gold badges.

---

So - is there an existing link I'm not aware of, or can anyone make [one of those database queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) that will tell me my *total score **and** number of non-community wiki answers* for any given tag?

Answer (score 10):

You will have to look under [Tags in your user profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers?tab=tags) for a quick overview, then manually hover over the numbers in grey boxes for the actual stats you're after:

[image]

So that's 16 upvotes away from a gold *word-choice* badge, for example. For *meaning*, it's 62, and for *etymology* you're missing 525 votes in addition to 75 more answers. And so on.

Comment: Brilliant! That's *exactly* what I wanted to know! For the immediate future I only need to consider the implications of dup VTC "votes" in respect of *single-word-requests, word-choice,* and *meaning*. If I haven't gotten used to the new system by the time any other categories go gold, I should probably find a less demanding way to fritter away my time online!

Answer (score 1):

You can actually extract an awful lot of information straight from the servers if you are willing and capable to fiddle a bit with SQL.

There are many ready-made and saved queries that could answer these kind of questions in detail as well.

Have a look at the [data stackexchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/queries).